# View item limit settings get changed automatically

Tags: list-view, row-limit

I have a strange problem. The item limit for the views get changed automatically without me changing anything. The item limit was initially set to "Display items in batches of specified size". Today, when I checked the settings it had got changed to "Limit the total number of items returned to the specified amount". I am wondering how that is possible?

The only change that happened to the view was removing some viewfields and adding others using the UI. Could this have caused the setting to have changed?

Thanks guys and gals for the help!

Comment: I vaguely recall this was a bug a long time ago in SP2007 days

Comment: which sharepoint version is this?

Comment: Are you a site collection administrator? Could it be that you have configured "happy hour" in your environment? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113564/how-to-use-happy-hour-in-list-view-threshold